# Why does my form not appear when I click the button?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

This is the code I use for my button. It appears, and the button is clickable.

```
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo ('<form>');
    echo ('<h3>Naam</h3>');'<br>';
    echo "<input type='submit' name='nameupdate' value='$pers->name' data-href='?persUp=".$pers->username."&persDa=".$pers->name."'>";
    echo ('</form>');
}
```

This form should be created when I click in the button, but it doesnt appear. Also the echo dabdab doesnt appear.

```
if(isset($_POST['nameupdate']))
{
    echo('dabdab');
    if(isset($_GET['persDa']))
    {
        $did = $_GET['persDa'];
        echo "<input type='text' name='nmbox' value='$did'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='nmupdate' value='Update'>";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Function for preview image.
$(function() {
    $(":file").change(function() {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#message').css("display", "none");
    $('#preview').css("display", "block");
    $('#previewimg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};


//Function for deleting preview image.
$("#deleteimg").click(function() {
    $('#preview').css("display", "none");
    $('#file').val("");
});

//Function for displaying details of uploaded image.
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $('#preview').css("display", "none");
    $('#message').css("display", "block");
});
});
```

and in the head:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/themerollertest.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using some javascript?

Comment: there is jquery involved

Comment: add this script it should be responsible for creating new element in page, there should be ajax script

Comment: Of course it wouldn't appear. Your form hasn't set a `method` attribute, so your `method` is GET. You have `if` condition with `$_POST`

Comment: i tried this      echo ('<form method="get" >');

Comment: but it still didnt work, same for post

Comment: No look at that he is using ajax to add new dom element there should be some script just check this part `data-href` is responsible for href and get, post is used in value

Comment: i did this: echo ('<form method="post" data-ajax="false">');

Comment: but it doesnt work yet

Comment: i cannot help you unless you provide me some javascript code i think you have some `$.ajax()` this is the place i need. You dont need form at all if you are using js and ajax

Comment: edited my question

Comment: no that is not it ..

Comment: thats all javascript I have

Comment: `echo ('<h3>Naam</h3>');'<br>';` doesn't throw any errors?

Comment: As much as i think Javascript you provided has nothing to do with the actual form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe too many () and wrong usage of PHP is case for this?

Your code:

```
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo ('<form>');
    echo ('<h3>Naam</h3>');'<br>';
    echo "<input type='submit' name='nameupdate' value='$pers->name' data-href='?persUp=".$pers->username."&persDa=".$pers->name."'>";
    echo ('</form>');
}
```

Should be:

```
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo '<form>';
    echo '<h3>Naam</h3><br>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="nameupdate" value="'.$pers->name.'" data-href="?persUp='.$pers->username.'&persDa='.$pers->name.'">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

**EDIT: Try this**

Form:

```
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
    echo '<h3>Naam</h3><br>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="persUp" value="'.$pers->username.'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="persDa" value="'.$pers->name.'">';

    echo '<input type="submit" name="nameupdate">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

And POST:

```
if(isset($_POST['nameupdate']))
{
    echo('dabdab');
    if(isset($_POST['persDa']))
    {
        $did = $_POST['persDa'];
        echo "<input type='text' name='nmbox' value='".$did."'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='nmupdate' value='Update'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$result` in your foreach()?

Comment: Does foreach works fine? does `$pers->name` prints out before form?

Comment: On all of the submit buttons, the right values are being displayed from the database, so foreach works fine

Comment: Cool! I m glad it worked! This is something what  D. Dimitrov said ;)

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you should use ajax for sending `POST` and `GET` by once for this i would recommend you to separate this pat to the new file

```
if(isset($_POST['nameupdate']))
{
    echo('dabdab');
    if(isset($_GET['persDa']))
    {
        $did = $_GET['persDa'];
        echo "<input type='text' name='nmbox' value='$did'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='nmupdate' value='Update'>";
    }
}
```

In the main file with the view you should add ajax like this

```
$("input[name='nameupdate']").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).data('href'),
        nameupdate = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: {
             nameupdate: nameupdate,
         },
         success: function (response) {
            // here you should choose place where to put your result 
             $('#result').html(response)
         }
     });
});
```

Edit: or simply change your code like this

```
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo '<form action="?persUp='.$pers->username.'&persDa='.$pers->name.'" method="POST">';
    echo '<h3>Naam</h3><br>';
    echo "<input type='submit' name='nameupdate' value=".$pers->name." data-href=''>";
    echo '</form>';
}
```